# symfony 3, arguments cant be passed to services(setArguments used)

Tags: php, symfony, service, containers

Updated:

I did the same thing in the AppBundle(the auto generated one), things works fine, and in the compiled version(in `var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php`)the parameters was passed in like following

```
return $this->services['app.roles'] = new \AppBundle\Role\RolesProvider(array(0 => 'ROLE_SUPER', 1 => 'ROLE_ADMIN', 2 => 'ROLE_USER'));
```

but in my generated bundle no parameter was passed in.

---

m building an app using symfony(version 3.1.6), got stucked.. any help was appreciated.

Details as following:

1.generate a bundle by using the 'symfony console tool'(none reusable selected)

2.create a service class like following.

```
class RolesProvider(){
        public function __construct(array $roles){
            //...
        }
}
```

services.yml:

```
services:
    user.roles.provider:
        class: UserBundle\Role\RolesProvider
```

3.my Extension class :

```
class UserExtension extends Extension {
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container) {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');

        $rolesProviderDef = $container->getDefinition('user.roles.provider');

        $rolesProviderDef->setArguments([
            $config['roles']
        ]);
    }
}
```

4.my Configuration class

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder() {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder;
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('user');
        $rootNode->children()
                ->arrayNode('roles')
                    ->prototype('scalar')->end()
                ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

5.config.yml:

```
user:
    roles: ["ROLE_SUPER", "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER"]
```

When i called `$this->get('user.roles.provider')`, it always give me an error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   UserBundle\Role\RolesProvider::__construct() must be of the type
>   array, none given,

had i missed some settings or so?

Updated---------:

i dumped the $config and $rolesProviderDef variable in the Extension class and got this

$config

```
array(1) {
 ["roles"]=>
 array(3) {
   [0]=>
   string(10) "ROLE_SUPER"
   [1]=>
   string(10) "ROLE_ADMIN"
   [2]=>
   string(9) "ROLE_USER"
 }
}
```

some code of $rolesProviderDef:

```
//...
["arguments":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "ROLE_SUPER"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "ROLE_ADMIN"
      [2]=>
      string(9) "ROLE_USER"
    }
  }

//...
```

Comment: Did you check `$config['roles']` really array ?

Comment: hi @MertÖksüz , i have dumped some variables, and update my post. thanks

Comment: I just duplicated your code and things work as expected.  I assume you are working in development mode?  Maybe try clearing the cache.  Your config dump has three roles but config.yml only has two?  Does 'symfony console tool' mean bin/console generate:bundle?  Since your var_dumps are working then your various class names are probably correct.

Answer (score 0):

`Definition::setArguments()` accepts an array of *all* arguments. Passing a `$config['roles']` generates somethink like this i:

```
// somewhere in the compiled container:
new RolesProvider("ROLE_SUPER", "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER");
```

I'm not sure that is problem, because it should cause other a type error. But may be it cause a wrong code generation (?)
Try this:

```
// note the additional brackets
$rolesProviderDef->setArguments([$config['roles']]); 

// or

// set only first one argument
$rolesProviderDef->replaceArgument(0, $config['roles']);
```

Comment: But dump of `["arguments":protected]=>...` contains only one-level array as though brackets are missed (?)

Comment: um.....now it should be right, the message says 'Type error: none arguments were given', and the Stack Trace shows some code (in var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php) like `return $this->services['user.roles.provider'] = new \UserBundle\Role\RolesProvider();`. should it be here?  i add another argument and the new one works well, but still got none with the $roles parameter

Comment: Yes, your arg should be in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php.  It is the compiled version of all the config stuff.  I can't see the error in your posted code.